# Make batch execute command on each line in my files

Tags: batch-file, active-directory

I'm trying to add computers to groups in AD. I do that with

```
net group GROUPNAME /Domain COMPUTERNAME$ /add
```

Would it be possible to make the command read two files containing the groups and workstations?

For example with theses:

workstations.txt

```
workstation1
workstation2
```

groups.txt

```
group1
group2
group3
```

Each workstations (1 and 2) will all have the three groups.

So far I have this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (machines.txt) do (
  set "machine=%%A"
  for /F "tokens=*" %%B in (gpos.txt) do (
    set "gpo=%%B"
    net group "!gpo!" /Domain !machine!$ /add 
  )
)
```

but I only get two commands. (The last group on all the two workstations)

Answer (score 1):

#### Can the command read two files containing the groups and workstations?

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f %%i in (workstations.txt) do (
  for /f %%j in (groups.txt) do (
    net group %%j /Domain %%i$ /add
    )
  )
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [net](http://ss64.com/nt/net.html)  - The NET Command is used to manage network resources.

Comment: If someone is adapting this script for some other type of list which contains spaces in the entries then you might want to adapt the script accordingly: `for /f "delims=" %%i in (yourlistfile.txt) do (`